# FastAPI Query Parameter Missing when Path Parameter is already specified

Tags: python, azure, docker, containers, fastapi

I have a FastAPI server running in a docker container on Azure, and when I sent a GET request to one of the endpoints it gives this error:

```json
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "query",
        "id"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to hit this endpoint:

```py
@app.get("/mines/{mine_id}")
def read_mine(mine_id):
    mine_ids = []
    with open(workdir + "mine_ids.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            mine_ids.insert(len(mine_ids), line.split())
    posX = -1
    posY = -1
    for i in range(len(mine_ids)):
        for j in range(len(mine_ids[0])):
            if mine_ids[i][j] == mine_id:
                posY = i
                posX = j

    if posY == -1 & posX == -1:
        return {"mine": "Invalid ID"}

    with open(workdir + "serial_numbers.txt", "r") as f:
        serial_numbers = []
        for line in f:
            serial_numbers.insert(len(serial_numbers), line.split())

    with open(workdir + "map.txt", "r") as f:
        rowsAndColumns = f.readline().split();
        rows = rowsAndColumns[0]
        columns = rowsAndColumns[1]

        print(rows + " " + columns)

        array = []
        for line in f:
            array.insert(len(array), line.split())

    if array[posY][posX] == "1":
        coordiates = [posX, posY]
        serial_number = serial_numbers[posY][posX]
    else:
        coordiates = "Does not exist"
        serial_number = "Does not exist"

    mine = {
        "coordiates": coordiates,
        "serial_number": serial_number
    }

    return {"mine": mine}
```

The problem is that I pass the Path Parameter `mine_id` and it works fine on `localhost`, but when I put it in a docker container and push it to Azure it gives the response I mentioned above.

If I pass the `mine_id` as a Path Parameter, and the `mine_id` as `id` as Query Parameter however it works fine on Azure, which is weird I don't understand what's happening. It also works like this fine like this on `localhost`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I appears as if the path function that you posted does not correspond to the endpoint you are calling. Could you share the exact call you are using that's causing the error?

Comment: https://<app-service-name>.azurewebsites.net/mines/lMN gives the error. https://<app-service-name>.azurewebsites.net/mines/lMN?id=lMN works fine.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also post everything that happens to `app`? Is it possible that the query parameter `id` is added somewhere else?

Comment: In my azure log stream it gives "GET /mines/lMN HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity", but for "GET /mines/lMN?id=lMN HTTP/1.1" 200 OK.

Comment: I think it's working again now, don't know exactly why maybe something to do with the container. Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked form me when i ran into the same error:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter,Depends, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional,List

router = APIRouter()

class SortModel(BaseModel):
    field:    Optional[str]

@router.get("/pydanticmodel")
def get_sort(criteria: SortModel = Depends(SortModel), directions: List[str] = Query(...)):
    pass #my code for handling this route.....
```